# error: ‘wxWebRequestEvent’ has not been declared Error despite having #include <wx/webrequest.h>

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, wxwidgets, codelite

I'm getting this error in the CodeLite IDE on my ubuntu OS, and I'm not sure why since I've done the proper #include <wx/webrequest.h>

```
Documents/CodeliteProjects/LearnFrench/modifyVocabFrame.cpp:75:10: error: 'wxWebRequest' was not declared in this scope
```

I've gone to the wxWebRequest sample in my wxWidgets-3.2 samples folder, and tried compiling it by using make in terminal and get these errors.

```
webrequest.cpp:29:2: error: #error "wxUSE_WEBREQUEST must be 1 for this sample."
   29 | #error "wxUSE_WEBREQUEST must be 1 for this sample."
      |  ^~~~~
webrequest.cpp:251:28: error: ‘wxWebRequestEvent’ has not been declared
```

wx-config says I have access to wxNet and all the other wxCore/Base libraries and it appears I have g++ on my system with the build-essentials, and can't seem to find msw, and the header file is in the proper spot. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

I tried exporting the wxUSE_WEBREQUEST=1 as an environment variable in terminal, didn't seem to solve the make errors. Not sure if I need to pass a flag to the compiler in the makefile, or something else entirely. It seems weird the makefile wouldn't have the proper flag set already if that's the issue, so I'm thinking it's something else, not quite sure what.

Comment: you need a #define or -D on the compile command, not an environment variable

Comment: @AstarWstar, you need to use proper `configure` option to turn on `WebRequest` support. Check `configure --help` output for details.

Comment: And/or you should check the output of config.log on why the option is not `ON`.

Comment: Configure doesn't seem to be a system wide command. I used find, and found about like 30 different files called "configure". I tried running libtools' configure, but like 7 missing dependencies/auxiliary files. The "bash-completion" 's configure doesn't run. Those were the only "share folder" configures available, the rest were snap folders / snap program configures.

Comment: I'm looking at libtool's config.log, the only plausible one I could find, is this it? And what am I looking for... a "wxUSE_WEBREQUEST=1" line? Don't see a line anything like that

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zdrneYy5 - Here's the config.log file, I removed the identifying info at the top of the config file.

Comment: @AstarWstar, how did you build the library? Or you just installed it f4om the repo? Please clarify.

Comment: If youdid build it - give the `exact` command sequence. If you installed from repo - which packages?

Comment: Just update the OP with the commands you used. Thx.

Comment: https://ibb.co/zsQrTZt - I downloaded the libraries using the Snap manager and here's a picture of the downloaded libraries. My WxWidgets code worked after downloading the wxWidgets libraries with Synaptic, but this is the first wxWidgets component (wxNet) it can't seem to use/find/something.

Comment: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial_xrc-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial_html-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial_qa-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_unofficial_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_unofficial_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_unofficial_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu_unofficial-3.2 . It appears I'm completely missing these libraries in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder and can't find them anywhere else on my system. Installed a bunch of wx unofficial 3.2 synaptic packages, so not sure what I'm missing. Is there a separate download for these libraries or do I /have/ to compile from the wxWidgets source?

Comment: @AstarWstar, what exact command you used to install wxWidgets? You can of course build wxWIdgets yourself but you should be able to install everything from the repo. Just update the OP with the `exact` command you used. I presume you are using (some version of) Ubuntu and so doing `apt-get install ....` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Turned out, the libraries from the Repo have wxWebRequest turned off by default for some reason (Or maybe I didn't have libcurl-dev at the time I installed the wx-3.2 libraries from the repos? Who knows). So I downloaded the wxWidgets Source code and compiled using ./configure, make, make install (I made sure wxUSE_WEBREQUEST=1 was in the make files before installing), and hooked up the newly created libraries in the IDE and it worked! Definitely not the answer I was looking for, but at least the source code compiled and it worked. Be nicer if the official Ubuntu repo libraries worked out of the box, but wxWidgets don't seem like they do.

Comment: you probably didn't pay attention to the missing cURL warning. But I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

`wxUSE_XXX` preprocessor symbols are defined as 0 or 1 when *building* the library. Under Unix this happens when running `configure` script, which generates the `wx/setup.h` file containing these definitions. If `wxUSE_WEBREQUEST` is 0 in your case, it means that support for `wxWebRequest` is simply not present in your version of the library.

To fix this, you need to either use the library from the system package, which should have it enabled, or build it yourself and check **your** `config.log` (not that of unrelated libtool package) created when you run `configure` to see whether support for it was enabled or not and why if it wasn't.

The most likely reason for the latter is that you don't have `libcurl-dev` package (which may also be called `libcurl4-dev`) installed. In this case you need to install it, and then rerun `configure` and `make` to build the library with `wxWebRequest` support.